# Navigation Drawer switch item managed from fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have implemented into Main Activity a Navigation Drawer that contains some items.
The Main Activity also cointains a viewPager that implements various fragments.
The onCreate:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);            

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    setUpViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.navigation_open,R.string.navigation_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

}

The Navigation Drawer so can be opened from all fragment views.
One of the items of the Navigation Drawer is a switch that I want to use into a fragment, for example to change background color or set text into a TextView "ON" or "OFF".

Inside the onCreateView of fragment i added:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and the

```
switch1= v.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);
```

is correctly recognised from the menu of NavigationDrawer.

Inside the fragment I added also:

```
    switch1= v.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);
    final TextView prova = v.findViewById(R.id.prova);

    NavigationView navigationView = v.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    SwitchCompat drawerSwitch = (SwitchCompat) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.simpleSwitch1).getActionView();
    drawerSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                prova.setText("ON");
            } else {
                // do other stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

and I got this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference
```

If I try to access in any mode to switch I get a null object reference.
How can I access to any item of the NavigationDrwawer?
The fragment is opened, so that switch needs to act as a "setting" switch only.